# Don't know how to display only one syso if i have more "if" who are satisfied

Tags: java

How i make this simple program to show me only one answer, if multiple conditions are satisfied like: if age<16 syso("you can't rent cars") and if age <18 syso("You can't vote").

For example, if i introduce 17 i want to display only ("You can't vote") not ("You can't vote" and "You can't rent cars").

I tried to use 2 conditions sticked by "&&", it didn't work.

**Code from comments**

```
 import java.util.Scanner; 

 public class Assign1 { 
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
     Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in); 
     int age; 
     System.out.println("Insert age "); 
     age = x.nextInt(); 
     if (age<16) { 
       System.out.println("You can't drive"); 
     } 
     if (age<18 && age<16) { 
       System.out.println("You can't vote"); 
     } 
     if (age<25) { 
       System.out.println("You can't rent cars"); 
     } 
     if (age>25) { 
       System.out.println("You can do anything "); 
     } 
   } 
 }
```

Comment: Show some code of what you have tried.

Comment: I tried to put the code in my question but this is why the site didn't let me...:"Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon."

Comment: This is what i tried: if (age<18) && if (age>16) {
       System.out.println("You can't vote");
      }
      if (age<25){
       System.out.println("You can't rent cars");

Comment: Well, then, did you check the editing help? Did you try to format your code according to the instructions given? Please try to read the [help] and understand error messages - it's important here as well as in your programming. One other thing you should avoid is putting code in the comments.

Comment: This is my code: import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assign1 {
       public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
        int age;
      System.out.println("Insert age ");
      age = x.nextInt();
      
      if(age<16){
       System.out.println("You can't drive");
      }
       if (age<18) & if (age<16) {
       System.out.println("You can't vote");
      }
      if (age<25){
       System.out.println("You can't rent cars");
      }
      if (age>25){
       System.out.println("You can do anything ");
      }
      
        }
        
       }

Comment: [The official Java tutorial - equality, relational and conditional operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

Answer (score 3):

This do what you want:

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int age = 17;




        if(age < 16){
            System.out.println("You can't drive");
        }
        else if(age < 18){
            System.out.println("You can't vote");
        }
        else if(age < 25){
            System.out.println("You can't rent cars");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("You can do anything");
        }
    }

}
```

output:

> You can't vote

The program print only the first if that is satisfied.

But i suggest you to study the conditional operators and logic. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

Comment: Yes but my task is to have only one answer per output. If i introduce 12 my output is -You can't vote You can't rent cars You can't drive-.          What i want is that when i introduce 12 to output only  "You can't drive". Sorry for beeing so fkin stupid.

Comment: @Stock It seems that again, you have not read the answer. It produces a *single* output. You ignored the message StackOverflow gave you when you didn't format your code. You ignored the comments where I asked you not to put code in comments and to read the help desk. Now you are ignoring the content of the answer. Please **read** what people write to you and try to understand it.

Comment: @Stock check my code, it will print only the first if that is satisfied!